# Mixcloud Widget API: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed, postmessage, mixcloud

On my website I would like to embed the Mixcloud iframe player and interact with it using the Widget JavaScript API (https://www.mixcloud.com/developers/widget/).

I am basically copying the code from the documentation:

```html
<script src="//widget.mixcloud.com/media/js/widgetApi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<iframe
    id="my-widget-iframe"
    src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?hide_cover=1&amp;mini=1&amp;light=1&amp;hide_artwork=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;feed=%2Feosradio%2Fani-kvirkvelia-27-may-2022%2F"
    width="100%"
    height="60"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="autoplay"
    ></iframe>
```

```js
var widget = Mixcloud.PlayerWidget(document.getElementById("my-widget-iframe"));
```

But there seems to be some error which seems to prevent the interaction of my JS with the Mixcloud object.

In Chrome (v118) nothing works and I get the following error message:

```
widgetApi.js:202 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://player-widget.mixcloud.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://127.0.0.1:5500').
```

While in Safari (v16) the message ready like this, but interaction with Mixcloud object seems to be possible nonetheless:

```
[Error] Unable to post message to https://player-widget.mixcloud.com. Recipient has origin http://127.0.0.1:5500
```

I tried it both on my localhost as well as on a website with https.
I had this working on a production website for several years (2020) and it recently stopped (September 2023).

Did Mixcloud change something? Or did browsers change? What can I do to resolve this?
Thank you for any help!